# Rewording or pluralization of one of the on-topic lines in the FAQ

Tags: discussion

Under the [on-topic page on the help](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) you have this line:

> Which tools, materials, and best practices for home improvement task.

It makes more sense, to me, to read it like this

> About tools, materials, and best practices for home improvement tasks.

Even if the first word is fine I think it should at least be pluralized.

Or maybe just add the word "a"

> Which tools, materials, and best practices for a home improvement task.

Answer (score 9):

It should definitely be "tasks" instead of "task", but I think it would read better without either "Which" or "About":

> ### We welcome these topics:
>
> ...
>
> Tools, materials and best practices for home improvement tasks.
>
> ...